# libgdx give position.x maximal end minimum range

Tags: android, libgdx, positioning, gyroscope

I am building an Android app and I'm using accelerometer/gyroscope with position.x but the object is going out of the screen. I was thinking to give position.x a minimum and a maximum so it will stay in the screen but how can I do it or is there an other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your ideea is good!
Calculate the left and right bounds of your screen and don't let the position.x value get outside of it.

Another way it would be to 'teleport' the position to the other side of your screen, like in Doodle Jump, but this depends of your game.